# SDL_TTF, Render Modes are identical in quality

Tags: c, graphics, sdl, antialiasing, sdl-ttf

I have a click based game to code, and It contains some text that need to be rendererd in real-time,I tried  to render the text with `TTF_RenderText_Solid()` , `TTF_RenderText_Shaded()`,`TTF_RenderText_Blended()` but they all render the same poor quality text. I have tried to change the BlendMode of the renderer, Surface and Texture, but still the same result, You might think it is because of using the same surface over and over, but I am sure it's not that.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iqkl.png)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

#define Title "Test"
#define font01 "src/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
#define font01_size 48

typedef struct {
    SDL_Texture *txtu;
    SDL_Rect rect;
    SDL_Color clr;
    char* text; 
} text_t;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    TTF_Init();

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(Title,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,480,720,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED|SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
    TTF_Font *font1 = TTF_OpenFont(font01,font01_size);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_Surface *Load_srfc = NULL;
    SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(Load_srfc,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    //SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET,480,720);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,0,255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer,NULL);
    SDL_Delay(500);

    text_t text1 = {NULL,{0,0,220,60},{255,255,255,240},"015:32.665 ms"};
    text_t text2 = {NULL,{20,70,220,60},{255,255,255,240},"015:32.665 ms"};
    text_t text3 = {NULL,{40,140,220,60},{255,255,255,240},"015:32.665 ms"};

    Load_srfc = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font1,text1.text,text1.clr);
    text1.txtu = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,Load_srfc);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(text1.txtu,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_FreeSurface(Load_srfc); Load_srfc=NULL;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,text1.txtu,NULL,&text1.rect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(500);

    SDL_Color back = {240,30,50,245};
    Load_srfc = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(font1,text2.text,text2.clr,back);
    text2.txtu = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,Load_srfc);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(text2.txtu,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_FreeSurface(Load_srfc); Load_srfc=NULL;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,text2.txtu,NULL,&text2.rect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(500);

    Load_srfc = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font1,text3.text,text3.clr);
    text3.txtu = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,Load_srfc);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(text2.txtu,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_FreeSurface(Load_srfc); Load_srfc=NULL;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,text3.txtu,NULL,&text3.rect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    
    bool quit=0;
    while(!quit)
    {
        SDL_Event evt;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&evt))
        {
            if(evt.type == SDL_QUIT ||
            (evt.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && evt.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE) ||
            (evt.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && evt.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)) {
                quit = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyTexture(text1.txtu);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(text2.txtu);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(text3.txtu);
    SDL_FreeSurface(Load_srfc);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Try clearing the screen between different renderings.

Comment: if you mean using `SDL_RenderClear(ren,NULL)` that wouldn't suite the goal of this code. and I doubt it would change anything.

Comment: Why "wouldn't suit"? I could be wrong, but it looks like you're stacking all those strings on top of each other, and if the first one has poor quality, you'll see it for the next strings too.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to change 2 and 3 to `TTF_R_Shaded` and `TTF_R_Blended`.

Comment: So did this solve the issue?

Comment: It did solve it, But still not satissfied tbh.

Comment: turns out I was missing a line: `SDL_QueurryTexture(renderner,NULL,NULL,&text1.rect.w,&text1.rect.h);` This it to give the rectangle the correct height wnd width instead of forcing it to your speculation about width and height, because scaling textures has side effects.